# swiftui button on a cell in list is not updating even if array does

Tags: list, swiftui, scrollview, updates

In this code I have the following problem, in the PreferredWebAppsMainView tab via the long pressure on a cell I remove the relevant app from the preferredAppList array. So far so good. However, when I switch to the StoreMainView tab, the cell appears in the right section, but I can't get the button updated, which shows '-' instead of + even if the cell appears in righ section, back to "available apps". Calling the same function but while I'm in the StoreMainView tab, everything works perfectly both cells and "signs" update correctly. From what I see, the objects in the arrays are updated correctly, but they don't update the "signs" of the button. Sorry for the lot of code, but I reduced at what I think could be issue related.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var classFromEntryPoint: ClassFromEntryPoint
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            PreferredWebAppsMainView()
                .tabItem { Label("Preferred", systemImage: "star") }
            StoreMainView()
                .tabItem { Label("Store", systemImage: "square.grid.3x1.below.line.grid.1x2") }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(.white)
        }
    }
    
}

//MARK: - PreferredWebAppsMainView
import SwiftUI
struct PreferredWebAppsMainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var classFromEntryPoint: ClassFromEntryPoint
    @State private var showConfirmAlert = false
    @State private var confirmMessage = ""
    @State private var selectedItemForAlert: WebAppModel? = nil
    let columns = [ GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100)) ]
    
    var body: some View {
        mainBodyWithGrid
    }
    
    private var mainBodyWithGrid: some View {
            ScrollView {
                if classFromEntryPoint.preferredAppList.isEmpty {
                    Text("Add app from the store")
                } else {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(classFromEntryPoint.preferredAppList) { item in
                            VerticalCellView(item: item)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 10, y: 10)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    let _ = print("will show web page for \(item.name)")
                                }
                                .onLongPressGesture {
                                    self.selectedItemForAlert = item
                                    self.confirmMessage = "Are you sure to remove app?"
                                    self.showConfirmAlert = true
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.top, 20) //gives a bit of padding at top of list
                }
        }.alert(self.confirmMessage, isPresented: $showConfirmAlert) {
            //remove and update the list
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) {
                Logger.debug(selectedItemForAlert?.name ?? "N/D")
                guard let app = selectedItemForAlert else {
                    Logger.error("no selectedItemForAlert")
                    return
                }
                withAnimation {
                    classFromEntryPoint.updateAvailabilityForApp(app) {
                        Logger.info("completion not used")
                    }
                }
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .destructive) { }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - WebAppModel
import SwiftUI
struct WebAppModel: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var isPreferred: Bool
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        
        isPreferred = false
    }
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, isAvailable: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isPreferred = isAvailable
    }
    
    static let fake = WebAppModel(
        id: 1,
        name: "Fake name",
        isAvailable: true
    )
}
extension WebAppModel: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: WebAppModel, rhs: WebAppModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
//MARK: - ClassFromEntryPoint
class ClassFromEntryPoint: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var downloadedAppList: [WebAppModel] = []
    @Published var preferredAppList: [WebAppModel] = []
    @Published var availableApps: [WebAppModel] = []
    
    init() {
        fakeLoadFromWebFunction()
    }
    
    func fakeLoadFromWebFunction() {
        self.downloadedAppList.append(WebAppModel(id: 1, name: "first"))
        self.downloadedAppList.append(WebAppModel(id: 2, name: "second"))
        self.downloadedAppList.append(WebAppModel(id: 3, name: "third"))
        splitBetweenLists()
    }
    
    func splitBetweenLists() {
        self.availableApps = downloadedAppList.filter { !($0.isPreferred)}.sorted(by: {$0.id < $1.id})
        self.preferredAppList = downloadedAppList.filter { $0.isPreferred }.sorted(by: {$0.id < $1.id})
        
        Logger.debug("availableApps: \(availableApps.count)")
        Logger.debug("preferredAppList: \(preferredAppList.count)")
    }
 
    ///moves WebApps between the two array based on isPreferred
    ///- use completion for UI updates
    func updateAvailabilityForApp(_ app: WebAppModel, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        if let index = downloadedAppList.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == app.id }) {
            // changeAvailability
            downloadedAppList[index].isPreferred = !(downloadedAppList[index].isPreferred)
            
            // update lists `availableApps` e `preferredAppList`
            splitBetweenLists()
                        
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - StoreMainView
import SwiftUI
struct StoreMainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var classFromEntryPoint: ClassFromEntryPoint
    
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    
    @State private var app: WebAppModel? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                
                Section(header: Text("Available apps")) {
                    if classFromEntryPoint.availableApps.isEmpty {
                        Text("no app available")
                    } else {
                        ForEach(classFromEntryPoint.availableApps) { app in
                            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                                    //********************************************************************************
                                    HStack {
                                        Image("ic_default") // placeholder
                                            .resizable()
                                            .scaledToFit()
                                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                            Text(app.name)
                                                .font(.headline)
                                            Text("app.description")
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                        }
                                        Spacer()
                                        Button {
                                            self.app = app
                                            self.alertMessage = "Add the app?"
                                            self.showingAlert = true
                                        } label: {
                                            Text(app.isPreferred ? "-" : "+")
                                        }
                                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) //required, otherwise the entire cell is tappable
                                        //********************************************************************************
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Preferred Apps")) {
                    if classFromEntryPoint.preferredAppList.isEmpty {
                        Text("no preferred app.")
                    } else {
                        ForEach(classFromEntryPoint.preferredAppList) { app in
                            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                                    //********************************************************************************
                                    HStack {
                                        Image("ic_default") // Immagine placeholder
                                            .resizable()
                                            .scaledToFit()
                                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                            Text(app.name)
                                                .font(.headline)
                                            Text("app.description")
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                        }
                                        Spacer()
                                        Button {
                                            self.app = app
                                            self.alertMessage = "Remove the app??"
                                            self.showingAlert = true
                                        } label: {
                                            Text(app.isPreferred ? "-" : "+")
                                        }
                                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) //required, otherwise the entrire cell is tappable
                                        //********************************************************************************
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Manage apps", displayMode: .automatic)
            .alert(self.alertMessage, isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) {
                    Logger.debug(app?.name ?? "N/D")
                    guard let app = app else {
                        Logger.error("no selectedItemForAlert")
                        return
                    }
                    withAnimation {
                        classFromEntryPoint.updateAvailabilityForApp(app) {
                            Logger.info("completion not used")
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                Button("Cancel", role: .destructive) { }
            }
            
            Text("Use left menu for navigation")
        }
        
    }
    
}

//MARK: - VerticalCellView
import SwiftUI
struct VerticalCellView: View {
    
    var item: WebAppModel
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        VStack {
            Image("ic_default") //  placeholder
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                .padding()
            VStack{
                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.8) //Reducing font dimentions up to 80%
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(height: 200)
        .background(.white)
    }
    
}
```